# Apple Wallet jpasskit apple device not recognizing when setting webserviceurl

Tags: java, ios, spring-boot, wallet, passkit

Working on a springboot application to download a pkpass file, it's working perfectly. But if I give a webserviceUrl to update the pass, it's not even recognizing in wallet.

i've used jpasskit library
webserviceurl : http://172.20.10.3:8080/wallet, since I'm using it in a local-environment.

Testing on ios 13.3 device
Any idea on this?
thanks

Comment: Have you enabled the http only option in the developer menu on the phone?  You’ll need a Mac and Xcode to do this, or use an https URL.

Comment: No I haven't done that, but I even tried some other https URL. Like https://google.com, that's also not working

Comment: I've tried setting up https in local that's also not working

Comment: Do you also have an authenticationToken? Hooking up to a Mac and seeing the console log of the phone as you install the pass will tell you why it is failing.

Comment: @PassKit  no, I'm running this in a windows machine and in the LAN I have an iphone 6s device. ANd when I set webserviceUrl safari is saying that "Cant donwload this file"

Comment: If you don’t have an authenticationToken in your pass.json and if the link is not https, it will fail to load.

Comment: @PassKit Yeah, it worked. Thank you!!!
Can I ask you one more thing, like when we update (swipe down in wallet). where is it calling or what endpoint is invoking.. cant see any calls..
Its very hard if we don't have enough documentation..

Can we do an update without push notification

Comment: Documentation for the web service is pretty clear and straightforward.  Pulling down calls the get latest version of a pass endpoint.

Comment: @PassKit I've tried that, but unfortunately no call is coming back to my local-server. Verified the webserviceUrl in the json. All looks good. But no call is happening. Any idea on this?

Comment: You really  need to access the log from the phone, but that is only possible with a Mac.  If you are using a self-signed certificate, then it will fail.

Comment: okay, then that might be the issue. I'm using a self signed certificate. Let me try something else.
Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: Actually it's hard to find a mac now. One more bit, so for just updating it with swipe down I just need the same endpoint right? webServiceURL/version/passes/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber 
No need to configure any other endpoints, correct me if im wrong..

Comment: You should configure all endpoints - if you are not implementing push then you can skip the serials endpoint, but devices will repeatedly try the register and I register endpoints if they don’t get the response they expect.